# SQL: Finding frequency of words used by a user

Tags: sql, sql-server, frequency

I am having a table with columns ID, CHAT_ID, USERNAME, MONTH, DAY, YEAR, STATUS.
[my_table][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XjM2.png

The status contains tweet by a user. Now I'm trying to find the frequency of words on status column grouping by username i.e., I need to create a new table which shows how many times a user uses a particular word. The table needs to have columns username, word and frequency. 
I used the following query to find frequency of words on status column

```
select sep.col AS WORD, count(*) as Frequency from
(
select * from 
(
select value = Lower
(RTrim
(LTrim
    (convert(VARCHAR(MAX), STATUS))
)) FROM My_table
) easyValues
        Where value <> '' 
    ) actualValues 
    Cross Apply dbo.SeparateValues(value, ' ') sep
    Group By USERNAME,sep.col 
    Order By Count(*) Desc
```

The dbo. SeparateValues() is a table valued function

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Function [dbo].[SeparateValues]    

(    
 @data VARCHAR(MAX),    
 @delimiter VARCHAR(10)     
)     
RETURNS     
@tbldata TABLE(col VARCHAR(MAX))    
As    
--Declare @data VARCHAR(MAX) ,@delimiter VARCHAR(10)     
--Declare @tbldata TABLE(col VARCHAR(10))    
--Set @data = 'hello,how,are,you?,234234'    
--Set @delimiter = ','    
--DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col VARCHAR(10))    
Begin    
DECLARE @pos INT    
DECLARE @prevpos INT    
SET @pos = 1     
SET @prevpos = 0    

WHILE @pos > 0     
BEGIN    
SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @data, @prevpos+1)    
if @pos > 0     
INSERT INTO @tbldata(col) VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@data, @prevpos+1, @pos-@prevpos-1))))    
else    
INSERT INTO @tbldata(col) VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@data, @prevpos+1, len(@data)-@prevpos))))    
SET @prevpos = @pos     
End    

RETURN       
END
```

I got it from the internet.
But I'm unable to do the part of finding the number of times the word was used by a user. I'm new to SQL, Can anyone please point me in a right direction to do so? Any help would be really appreciated. thank you!

Comment: This is a select and you are talking about creating a table. I think you are looking for SELECT INTO. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: Sorry my earlier question was vaguely written, can you please help in right direction of doing the above task

Comment: Show the code of SeparateValues() function

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: SQL Server management studio